# Stored Procedure Outbound Gateway is failing to execute a valid stored procedure

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We are using spring-integration in our project. I am using `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway` to execute a stored procedure. I am getting the following error when I use Spring-Integration layer to hit the stored procedure.But strangely the same stored procedure is getting executed successfully from SQL Developer and inserting the required row into the table.

```
2016-07-01 11:45:49,254 DEBUG http-0.0.0.0-8080-4 [org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator] Translating SQLException with SQL state '65000', error code '6550', message [ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
]; SQL was [{call ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}] for task [CallableStatementCallback]
```

The following is my `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway`:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
                        id="PQPutUserBAInformation-AWD-StoredProcedure2" 
                        auto-startup="true"
                        data-source="routingDataSource" 
                        stored-procedure-name="ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA"
                        skip-undeclared-results="true"
                        ignore-column-meta-data="true"  
                        use-payload-as-parameter-source = "false" 
                        expect-single-result="true" >

                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_USERID" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_BUSINESSAREA" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_SELECTEDIND" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_DEFAULTIND" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LEGACYSYSTEM" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LEGACYLOGIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LEGACYPASSWORD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_OTHERLOGIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_OTHERPASSWORD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ADDSECURLOGIN" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_ADDSECURPASSWORD" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LASTUPDATEUSERID" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />
                        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="P_LASTUPDATE" direction="IN" type="VARCHAR" />


                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_USERID" expression="#xpath(payload, '//CurrentUserID')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_BUSINESSAREA" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/Code')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_SELECTEDIND" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/Selected')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_DEFAULTIND" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/Default')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LEGACYSYSTEM" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/LegacySystem')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LEGACYLOGIN" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/LegacyLogin')" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LEGACYPASSWORD" expression="headers.LegacyPassword" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_OTHERLOGIN" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/OtherLogin')" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_OTHERPASSWORD" expression="headers.otherPassword" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ADDSECURLOGIN" expression="#xpath(payload, '//SelectedBusinessArea/AddSecurLogin')" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_ADDSECURPASSWORD" expression="headers.addSecurPassword" />

                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LASTUPDATEUSERID" expression="#xpath(payload, '//userID')" />
                        <int-jdbc:parameter name="P_LASTUPDATE" expression="#xpath(payload, '//dateTimeStamp')" />

                <int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="rowMapper" row-mapper="com.dsths.cs.awd.utils.ResultSetRowMapper"/>
```

The following is some of the log file content received in the debug mode:

```
2016-07-01 11:45:48,505 DEBUG http-0.0.0.0-8080-4 [org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall] The following parameters are used for call {call ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)} with: {P_LEGACYLOGIN=ratna, P_ADDSECURPASSWORD=, P_SELECTEDIND=N, P_OTHERPASSWORD=, P_BUSINESSAREA=CS2XAA, P_USERID=DT76747, P_DEFAULTIND=Y, P_OTHERLOGIN=, P_LASTUPDATE=2016-07-01-11.45.21.000590, P_ADDSECURLOGIN=, P_LASTUPDATEUSERID=DT76747, P_LEGACYSYSTEM=Amisys, P_LEGACYPASSWORD=engan}

.............


Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The stored procedure is below:

```
create or replace procedure ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA
(
    P_USERID in types.char10,
    P_BUSINESSAREA in types.char10,
    P_SELECTEDIND in types.char1,
    P_DEFAULTIND in types.char1,
    P_LEGACYSYSTEM in types.char10,
    P_LEGACYLOGIN in types.char16,
    P_LEGACYPASSWORD in types.char16,
    P_OTHERLOGIN in types.char10,
    P_OTHERPASSWORD in types.char10,
    P_ADDSECURLOGIN in types.char10,
    P_ADDSECURPASSWORD in types.char10,
    P_LASTUPDATEUSERID in types.char10,
    P_LASTUPDATE in types.char26
)
authid current_user
as
    TOTALCNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;

begin
    select count(*) into TOTALCNT 
    from USERBUSINESSAREA 
    where USERID = P_USERID
    and BUSINESSAREA = P_BUSINESSAREA;

    if ( TOTALCNT = 0 )
    then
        insert into USERBUSINESSAREA     
        ( 
            USERID,
            BUSINESSAREA,
            SELECTEDIND,
            DEFAULTIND,
            LEGACYSYSTEM,
            LEGACYLOGIN,
            LEGACYPASSWORD,
            OTHERLOGIN,
            OTHERPASSWORD,
            ADDSECURLOGIN,
            ADDSECURPASSWORD,
            LASTUPDATEUSERID,
            LASTUPDATE 
        ) 
        values
        (
            P_USERID,
            P_BUSINESSAREA,
            P_SELECTEDIND,
            P_DEFAULTIND,
            P_LEGACYSYSTEM,
            P_LEGACYLOGIN,
            P_LEGACYPASSWORD,
            P_OTHERLOGIN,
            P_OTHERPASSWORD,
            P_ADDSECURLOGIN,
            P_ADDSECURPASSWORD,
            P_LASTUPDATEUSERID,
            P_LASTUPDATE
        );
    end if;
end;
```

Can any one please help me out what could be the wrong here?

Comment: Please, share the stored procedure  definition

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for the response.I have included the stored procedure definition in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `procedure ZSPPQINSERTUSERIDBA` it is just *procedure* without any returns. That's why your `<int-jdbc:returning-resultset name="rowMapper">` is like a wrong and extra argument causing that error.

So, consider to use `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-channel-adapter>` - one-way exactly for `void` procedures component.

Comment: Thanks... +1 for quick response