# Unable to create Oracle function with such type of datatypes

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

Please help me on, how to create a function with below data types?

```
create or replace FUNCTION              "SUSPENDTIME" 
( 
 keydate in types.char10, 
 keytime in types.char8)
```

Getting error as `datatypes` not found.

I tried to create types below but not working

CREATE or replace TYPE types AS OBJECT
    ( char10        char(10), char8        char(8), char6        char(6),
    char1        char(1), char2        char(2), char21        char(21)
    );

Line/Col: 1/42 PLS-00201: identifier 'TYPES.CHAR10' must be declared

Comment: What is `types.char10` supposed to be?

Comment: This stored procedure is running from a JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would probably be just

```
create or replace function suspendtime (keydate in varchar2,
                                        keytime in varchar2)
```

Though, perhaps it could even be a single parameter:

```
create or replace function suspendtime (keydatetime in date)
```

---

**[EDIT: after seeing your comment]**

It looks like a user-defined collection of types. Something like this:

Package whose name is `types`, which contains certain subtypes:

```
SQL> create or replace package types as
  2    subtype char10 is varchar2(10);
  3    subtype num81  is number(8, 1);
  4  end types;
  5  /

Package created.
```

A function which uses those types:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test (par_ename in types.char10)
  2    return types.num81
  3  is
  4    retval number;
  5  begin
  6    select sal into retval
  7      from emp
  8      where ename = par_ename;
  9    return retval;
 10  end;
 11  /

Function created.
```

Does it work?

```
SQL> select f_test('KING') from dual;

F_TEST('KING')
--------------
          5000

SQL>
```

Yes, it does.

---

Therefore, if you want to use `types.char10` and similar, you'll have to create them first. If you didn't, you can't expect `SUSPENDTIME` function to compile.

Comment: Please see stored procedure in below url also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138982/stored-procedure-outbound-gateway-is-failing-to-execute-a-valid-stored-procedure

Comment: Perfect, I was trying this kind of solution. Amazing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to know are you using the correct datatype for your columns? i can see it can be date datatype from the name.
But anyway below is the syntax :

```
create or replace function 
SUSPENDTIME
 (keydate in varchar2,
  keytime in varchar2)
End SUSPENDTIME;
```

Comment: It's expected datatypes only. Just for your reference, please find similar stored procedure  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138982/stored-procedure-outbound-gateway-is-failing-to-execute-a-valid-stored-procedure

Comment: ok i thought as date and time is attached to keydate and keytime field respectively so it should be of date datatype...but you can create varchar2 datatype

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't pass datatypes. This function is already working in production. I think, through JDBC. Now this function need to modified through pl sql developer. Please suggest.